# Storing and comparing time for multiple timezones

Tags: mysql, timezone

### I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `config` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time` time NOT NULL,
  `zone` char(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `time_zone` (`time`,`zone`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

Looking like this:

```
ID  TIME        ZONE
-----------------------------
3   00:07:36    Pacific/Apia
1   10:01:50    Europe/London
2   12:07:20    Asia/Thimbu
4   00:01:50    US/Hawaii
```

The table shows different times in different countries, I need to know which ones are happening now.

How can I return all the `ID`s for which the time is *now*?

### Example Result:

If the current **UTC** time is **10:01:50** I would want to return the following rows:

```
ID  TIME        ZONE
-----------------------------
1   10:01:50    Europe/London
4   00:01:50    US/Hawaii
```

London is UTC +0, and Hawaii is UTC -10, so both are happening now.

---

I know MySQL has all the timezone information built-in, but I don't know how to query it.

Comment: Does this help? SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2012-06-07 12:00:00', 'GMT', 'America/New_York');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(CONCAT(CURDATE(),' ',time),zone,'GMT') FROM config;
+---------------------------------------------------+
| CONVERT_TZ(CONCAT(CURDATE(),' ',time),zone,'GMT') |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| 2013-10-31 10:01:50                               |
| 2013-10-31 11:07:36                               |
| 2013-10-31 10:01:50                               |
| 2013-10-31 06:07:20                               |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Note that this makes assumptions about the dateline that are going to be incorrect in terms of both date and (at specific times of year) time.